# Could I retrieve the accessibility to Google Colaboratory after the usage limitation?

Tags: google-colaboratory

According to Google's FAQ webpage, Google often hampers heavy users from using GPU and TPU at Google Colaboratory. I think that I ran into trouble due to this reason. However, the document does not state whether users who Google regulated can reuse this service. If you know about the issue, please share your experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I post my experience here. Though I could not use Google Colab at that time, the constraint was released after one day.